# What is the time complexity for adding a String,String entry to a HashMap in Java?

Tags: java

If we have a `HashMap<String,String> H`, and we use the code `H.put("Hello","World")`. 
Would the time complexity be the same as in the case where we use an integer key-value pair in a HashMap? I feel that the performance with String should be poorer, as hashing the String would be an O(String length) operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's performance will be poorer since hashing a string is indeed slower then hashing an integer.

In fact, Java uses a specific formula for `hashCode()` of String, which you can see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_hashcode.htm), and it does check all the charachters of the string, as you would expect.

In my Eclipse the code for `hashCode()`:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

But why are you comparing these two things? It doesn't make much sense to compare complexity of two algorithms which do **different things**.

Comment: I didn't mean to compare, I was wondering if there is any drop in performance due to the length of string.

Comment: Yes. You can even see the code for `String.hashCode()` in your eclipse and see the loop. (see edit in my answer)